# what does vendor specific OUI type in 802.11 frames mean

Tags: beacon, vendor, wifi

I'm working on IEEE802.11.
In the captured beacon frames i found there is a vendor specific OUI type Byte coming after the 3 Bytes OUI, can u explain what this means?

802.11 Beacon Frame:

[image: 802.11 beacon frame]

Comment: It means this is an attribute that the vendor (Cisco in your case) invented, you need to talk to Cisco to try to get documentation on what that byte means. (They ususally ignore such requests unless you're a very big and well paying customer)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unluckily i'm not such a customer :(